# Creating SVN Repo and Checking Out

Tags: linux, svn

I'm moving my current server contents to a new one, and am currently in the process of setting up SVN. I'm fairly unfamiliar with SVN, typically using it to the extent of commits and updates.

I have two locations that I use SVN on the old server:

PROD location:

```
/var/www/html/new_dwutils/
```

and local:

```
/home/{user_name}/public_html/new_dwutils/
```

My interaction svn-wise is normally committing and updating at the /new_dwutils/ level.

**Note: Running `svn --version` says I'm at version 1.6.11 for both servers.**

I'm now trying to recreate this structure on the new server. My initial thought was to create the svn repo using something like:

```
svnadmin create /var/www/html/new_dwutils/
```

This creates the repo dir, but, when I copy my files into the dir, I am unable to do svn commands like `status`. However, when I go into a sub-dir of the copied data, I can use the svn commands.

This has me thinking that the repo is /new_dwutils/ and the copied data is considered a project? And the sub-dirs are working copies then?

Going off that thought, I deleted the repo, and made the html dir a repo:

```
svnadmin create /var/www/html/
```

I then copied my new_dwutils dir, and sure enough, I was able to do svn commands like I use too. What I've noticed is that when creating the repo, a few things are added that were not on the previous server: `conf/`, `db/`, `format`, `hooks/`, `locks/`, and `README.txt`. I get that these are svn files, but I'm not seeing the .svn file. I know that there was an update for svn that "removed" .svn files, but these files are now in `/var/www/html/`.

Now I want to setup my local working copy.

I've been doing (location `/home/{user_name}/public_html/`):

`svn checkout file:///var/www/html/`

Problem is it copies the `html/` file, but nothing in it, and I don't want the `html/` file  I want the `html/new_dwutils/` file.

I feel like I'm doing it wrong from the start, and would greatly appreciate some explanation on how to get on the right track. A step by step would be extremely useful, and if further clarification is need for files or directory paths, I would gladly detail.

Thanks!

Comment: You're attempting to create a repository where you should be creating a **working copy** (by checking out from a repository elsewhere). You really need to read the [Subversion manual](http://svnbook.org/) before you dig yourself in any deeper.

Comment: @alroc I'm creating a new repo at `/var/www/html/`, and trying to make a working copy (checkout) at `/home/{user_name}/public_html`. I'm assuming I need to create a new repo since the old server is going to be removed, and I won't be able to reference the repo on it.

Comment: You can move the old repository to the new server (see the manual for how). And you definitely should **not** be putting the repository in the public `wwwroot` as you're doing here.

Comment: @alroc This might be common knowledge, but why would I not want to put the repo in `/var/www/html/`?

Comment: If it's in the public `wwwroot`, anyone can make a full copy of your repository, its configuration and any hook scripts. Hook scripts might contain passwords. And there's no reason *to* put the repository there in the first place, as it needs to be accessed via the server libraries, which can be pointed at any (more secure) location on your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Subversion Manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) will answer all of your questions.

If you're making a Subversion repository under `/var/www.html`, I'm assuming you're using Apache httpd as your server. Look at [Chapter 6](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html). If you already have a repo, create a dump file, then use that dump file to recreate the repo. Look at [Chapter 5](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.moving-and-removing.html) on moving repositories.

If you don't know anything about Subversion, or are confused by the difference between the repository location directory and a working directory, read [the on-line manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com). It's one of the best pieces of documentation I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

From description of your question it appears that '/var/www/html/new_dwutils/' is your working copy and not a repo.

Go to '/var/www/html/new_dwutils/' on the old server and type "svn info" this should give you location of the old repo. You should simply be able to 'svn co ' into the new location to checkout a copy of all your files from the old server (everything that is checked in - you will not get anything that is not checked in on the old server).

However, if your repo was local on the old server and you want to move it to your new server too. Then you can simply copy the entire folder to the new server and access it directly using its new location in 'svn co' command.